# Is it okay to use "and", "or" etc. instead of "&&", "||"?

Tags: c++, operators, standards

I'm used to the `and` and `or` keywords in C++. I've always used them and typing them is fast and comfortable for me. Once I've heard that these aliases are non-standard and may not work on all compilers. But I'm not sure of it, I don't really know if it's true.
Let's assume that I give someone my code, will he have problems compiling it?
Is it all right when I use `and`, `or` instead of `&&`, `||`? Or are these keywords really non-standard?
P.S.I use the MinGW compiler.

Comment: End this heresy, lest thy soul be forever damned!

Comment: It's standard, but a complete mental speed-bump for those who don't know about it. You're better off dropping the practice, because your code with be closer to what people readily expect to read. (In other words, using what other people use makes it more readable.)

Comment: It could be worse; it could be [trigraphs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt0y4awe.aspx).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

They are in fact standard in C++, as defined by the ISO 14882:2003 C++ standard 2.5/2 (and, indeed, as defined by the 1998 edition of the standard). Note that they are built into the language itself and don't require that you include a header file of some sort.

However, they are **very rarely** used, and I have yet to see production code that actually uses the alternative tokens. The only reason why the alternative tokens exist in the first place is because these characters on some keyboards (especially non-QWERTY ones) were either nonexistent or clumsy to type. It's still in the standard for backwards compatibility.

Even though they are standard, I highly recommend that you don't use them. The alternative tokens require more characters to type, and the QWERTY keyboard layout already has all the characters needed to type out C++ code without having to use the alternative tokens. Also, they would most likely bewilder readers of your code.

> **2.5/2 Alternative tokens**
>
> In all respects of the language, each
>   alternative token behaves the same,
>   respectively, as its primary token,
>   except for its spelling. The set of
>   alternative tokens is defined in Table
>   2.

```
Table 2 - alternative tokens
+--------------+-----------+
| Alternative  |  Primary  |
+--------------+-----------+
|    <%        |    {      |
|    %>        |    }      |
|    <:        |    [      |
|    :>        |    ]      |
|    %:        |    #      |
|    %:%:      |    ##     |
|    and       |    &&     |
|    bitor     |    |      |
|    or        |    ||     |
|    xor       |    ^      |
|    compl     |    ~      |
|    bitand    |    &      |
|    and_eq    |    &=     |
|    or_eq     |    |=     |
|    xor_eq    |    ^=     |
|    not       |    !      |
|    not_eq    |    !=     |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: "still in the standard for backwards compatibility"... backwards compatibility with what? C didn't have `and` and `or` nor did older versions of C++.

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves: With older C++ code that did use them. Generally, the C++ Standards Committee strives to avoid breaking older, existing C++ code if possible.

Comment: So why were they added in the first place? My 1991 copy of "The C++ Programming Language" makes no mention of these tokens, and post-1991 seems a bit late to be making computers that don't have `&` or `|` on the keyboard...

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves: The C programming language had [some of these alternative tokens via a header file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h), and since C++ is meant to be backwards compatible with C, the C++ standard made it a built in part of the language. You're also forgetting about non-QWERTY keyboards where some of the primary tokens are not easy to type.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Thanks for fixing the coloring of the ASCII-art table. :-)

Comment: Note that the requirement was also in the 1998 version of the standard; it is not new in the 2003 edition.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Right. All I had on hand was the 2003 version, and I quoted the relevant parts in that. :-)

Comment: It actually seems as though *adding* this would break backward compatibility because so many programs might be using these keywords as identifiers.

Comment: @casablanca: This feature is practically ancient in the C and C++ programming languages. It was probably in the standards since the very beginning. Of course, you can't have 100% backwards compatibility (e.g. the `class` keyword), but generally the standards committee strives to not break existing code.

Comment: The xor primary should be ^ (I don't have the rep to edit it).

Comment: @In silico: I don't know about the specs, but at least [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h), these are just macros in C, introduced in 1995, and I would have preferred it to be the same in C++. Adding new keywords to a mature language is always a bad idea.

Comment: @casablanca: You're going to have to ask the C++ standards committee why they made `<ciso646>` a "no-op" and the alternative tokens built-in. I believe some compilers have a switch that turns them on/off.

Comment: @In silico: Indeed, VC++ has them off by default, which I think is a good idea.

Comment: I experimented and developed a preference for using these keywords, and do so when I don't need portability to stupid compilers that don't provide them.  Obviously C++ will introduce new keywords from time to time... there can reasonably be command line switches to disable them, but they should default to being on.  Dirty move by MS.

Comment: @Tony: How in the world did you develop a preference for these keywords? I know no C++ book or tutorial where these alternative keywords were presented. They require more typing and most people would be surprised with the alternative tokens. You assert that these alternative tokens should be on by default, but casablanca obviously disagrees with you. You can't really say that it's a "dirty move" by MS - since almost nobody uses the alternative tokens, one can see how it's justified turning them off by default.

Comment: @In silico: I don't wait around for some tutorial or book to use a language feature before considering it.  More typing?  It's easier to type "and" than shift-6-6, and "or" is as short as "||".  Should I be worried that casablanca disagrees?  Does he know something the committee didn't when they added them to the Standard?  And how can you so confidently state that nobody uses them, let alone that nobody would use them if MS didn't make it a portability issue?

Comment: @In silico: after using Python for a while, you realize that it's stupid to use some gibberish `&&` rather than a simple word. It's much harder to type `bitand` instead of `and` than it is to type `&` instead of `&&`, and frankly I do think it gains in readability. I still can't understand why people cling to using as weird operators as they can, really makes me think of 1337 speak. That said, I do use the gibberish version at work to conform to the "norm".

Comment: @Tony @Matthieu M : The reason why we have these "weird" notations is because we use them frequently enough that coming up with these operators is justifiable. It's like mathematics, we use "weird" notations for mathematical equations because it's a lot easier to write out `f(x) = 2(x+1)` than it is to write out `the function of x is equal to two times the sum of x and one`. There's a reason why we don't try to use English to emulate programming languages.

Comment: @In silico: I've used those "weird" operators for decades and have no particular issue with them, but after trying "not", "and" and "or" I can only say I think they improve the code readability, and I like the contrast between the Alternative tokens for logical operators and the Primary tokens that I continue to use for bitwise operations.  Reflects "everyday" logic vs comp sci bit hackery. Your analogy with `f(x)` just doesn't hold for "not", "and" and "or" - even where there is a difference in brevity it's much smaller and less significant, and there's no issue with precision/ambiguity.

Comment: @In silico: One other point: I'm glad Mr Stroustrup's had the perspective of an educator... I'm sure if you'd had to explain to new C++ students the quirks of the language 10000 times you'd start to have a clearer impression of the divide between genuinely useful and necessary, and arbitrary and weird.  People coming from other languages where "and" is just "and" won't be moved by your arguments or the history.

Comment: @Tony: I still think the math analogy holds. I'm not saying that we should write code like [Conways' Game of Life in APL](http://catpad.net/michael/apl/), I'm all for readable code. But I also like concise code. I would point out that we have have this exact same discussion about COBOL and BASIC, so perhaps we both just have different preferences with regard to the operators.

Comment: @Tony: Concerning your point about C++ students, C++ is not meant to be a teaching language, it's meant to be a *practical* language. For all the things C++ must do, like being general purpose and be backwards compatible with C, it does the job well. It's of course not perfect, but it's not like we can start over. There are reasons why C++ was designed the way it is. Students are more than capable of understanding the language, as there are plenty of C++ experts on Stack Overflow and I'm sure they were all noobs at one point.

Answer (score 9):

These keywords ARE standard and are described in section 2.5 of the standard.  Table 2 is a table of these "alternative tokens".  You can use them all you want, even though everyone will hate you if you do.

Answer (score 5):

They are standard in the new c++0x standard. Up-to-date modern compilers should recognise them, although I don't believe they are obliged to yet. Whatever floats your boat, I assume.

Comment: They were not added in 0x, they've been there forever.

Comment: he doesn't say they were, I think he was merely pointing out that they are *still* a standard.

Answer (score 4):

they're standard C++, but with older compilers and possibly also with MSVC 10.0 (i haven't checked) you may have to include a special header, [isosomethingsomething.h]

cheers & hth.,

Comment: `<ciso646>`. (Which itself is just, as usual, a wrapper around the C header `iso646.h` where the macros are defined, in C. In C++, the header should be empty, as alternative tokens are built-in and do not require any macros to use.)

Comment: Thanks, I've found it - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ciso646/ - but I'm not sure if I'll use it any more. I mean the Mark Storer's comment and the Noah Roberts' answer... now I see that generally people don't like these keywords. I will probably have to stop using them.

Answer (score 4):

I have always messed up ^ (xor) and the ~ (two complement) operators. With the alternative tokens (that I believe should be primary ones) there is no question about what they do, yes, I agree with former posters that the textual ones are much more descriptive.

There is another possible messup using the digraphs, it is possible to forget one of the characters in ||, && that will cause subtle bugs and strange behaviours.
With the textual operators, it is much harder to make such a mistake.

I believe what I mentioned above are real valid arguments to improve code safety and clarity. Most C++ programmers SHOULD in my opinion try to get used to the textual operators in favor of the old cryptic ones.

I am surprised that so few programmers know about them. These operators should have taken over  long time ago as I see it.

Answer (score 3):

It's syntactically valid, given those are required [alternative tokens](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex.digraph#2).

> In all respects of the language, each alternative token behaves the same, respectively, as its primary token, except for its spelling.

However, some tokens are used for more than just logical or bitwise operators. So one can see the idiosyncratic:

```
auto& foo(auto and T) { // C++20 forwarding reference
    return T;
}
```

Or even

```
auto& foo(auto bitand T) { // lvalue reference
    return T;
}
```

That's gonna make one scratch their head for a while.

Comment: I think 'idiosyncratic' is putting it mildly.  This is an abuse of these keywords.

Comment: @PaulSanders - I'd lay any abuse claims at the feet of those who use different tokens for woefully different purposes. Then add alternative spelling on the token level. I'm not gonna fault someone being cute.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, i've been using and looking at many C++ code examples for years.. and never, until now, knew about these so I guess that means most people don't use them. So, for the sake of consistency (if you plan on working in group projects etc) it's probably best to make a habit of using && and ||.

Answer (score 1):

Section 2.5 of the ISO/IEC 14882:1998 standard (the original C++ standard) says:

> #### §2.5 Alternative tokens [lex.digraph]
>
> 1 Alternative token representations are provided for some operators and punctuators<sup>16)</sup>.
>
> 2 In all respects of the language, each alternative token behaves the same, respectively, as its primary token,
>   except for its spelling<sup>17)</sup>. The set of alternative tokens is defined in Table 2.
>
> <sup>16)</sup> These include “digraphs” and additional reserved words. The term “digraph” (token consisting of two characters) is not perfectly
>   descriptive, since one of the alternative preprocessing tokens
>   is %:%: and of course several primary tokens contain two characters.
>   Nonetheless, those alternative tokens that aren’t lexical keywords are colloquially known as “digraphs”.
>
> <sup>17)</sup> Thus the “stringized” values (16.3.2) of [ and <: will be different, maintaining the source spelling, but the tokens can otherwise be
>   freely interchanged.

```
                 Table 2—alternative tokens
_______________________________________________________________________________
    alternative  primary  |  alternative  primary  |  alternative  primary
     <%            {      |     and          &&    |    and_eq       &=
     %>            }      |    bitor         |     |    or_eq        |=
     <:            [      |     or           ||    |    xor_eq       ^=
     :>            ]      |     xor          ^     |     not         !
     %:            #      |    compl         ~     |    not_eq       !=
     %:%:          ##     |    bitand        &     |
_______________________________________________________________________________
```

There is no discussion of 'if you include some header' (though in C, you need `#include <iso646.h>`).  Any implementation that does not support the keywords or digraphs is not compliant with the 1998 edition, let alone later editions, of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously in regards to backward compatability the "and/or" keywords are not the issue. I would believe them to be the newer standard. It is just old programmers not understanding that some noob might have to be able to read the code and not want to look up what && means. Then again if any IT department is worth it's salt it will make the programmers conform to the standards of the company! That is my belief so (and/or) are futuristic and real possible standard going towards the future. && is backward compatable not(pun) (and/or).

Comment: Please don't answer old threads that already have thorough answers from 1 year ago!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use '*' instead of && and '+' instead of ||