# My C++ code goes into infinite loop when array size increases

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to solve the problem at: [Cut the Sticks](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-sticks).

My code works fine when the array size <=3 but goes bonkers then the size increases to >=6

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int minElement(int a[]){
    int min = a[0];
    int k;
    for (k=1; k < 6; k++){
        if (a[k] < min and a[k] > 0)
            min = a[k]; 
    }
    return min;
}


int main(){
    int a[6];
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int minElem, flag;
    while (true){
        flag = 0;
        minElem = minElement(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            a[i] = a[i] - minElem;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            if (a[j] > 0){
                cout<<a[j]<<endl;
                flag++;
            }

        }

        if (flag == 0)
            break;

    };
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is arising in the minElement function, it seems. On print min after assignment, it shows min as empty. Similarly, inside  the loop in the function, I am getting blanks for all mins. What could be the issue?

**EDIT**

Please try the code here: `http://cpp.sh/2ti6` with the input as [5,4,4,2,2,8]. It doesn't reach zero, the code starts failing before the first iteration, when the minimum element is called as Nothing is returned from the minElement functionn

Comment: All the hard-coded sixes most likely aren't helping. Step through your code in a debugger.

Comment: Have you considered what happens min = a[0]; results in min being a negative number?

Comment: It compiles fine, I'll change that though

Comment: @Elemental in fact 'and' _is_ standard C++ (I'm assuming that's what you were objecting to): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251699/is-it-okay-to-use-and-or-etc-instead-of

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes? I had a genuine query tha couldn't be resolved reading the docs and you guys helped me learn an important concept. Why the downvotes, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is there because of this line in the code

```
int min = a[0];
```

you need to check that array element is non-zero

```
int minElement(int a[]){
    int min = 0;
    int i=0;
    while(i<6)  // check the array element is non -zero
    {
        if(a[i]>0){
            min = a[i];
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    //int min = a[0];
    int k;
    for (k=1; k < 6; k++){
        if (a[k] < min && a[k] > 0)
            min = a[k]; 
    }
    return min;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP is trying to solve a problem, you shouldn't just hand out a solution.

Comment: It is not zero, interestingly. My first element is 5.

Comment: @randomnessrandomly, use `break;` after getting non- zero element.

Comment: Try this code here: http://cpp.sh/2ti6. With the input as [5,4,4,2,2,8]. By this code I mean, the code that I originally posted

Comment: @randomnessrandomly, i tried and i am getting this output. check `if(a[i] > 0)` as you are having negative numbers also.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your `minElement` function.

In the case that a[0] happens to be zero, you'll never assign another value to min and will return zero. Out of the function you will subtract zero to the values and enter the infinite loop.

In the case that a[0] is a negative number, you'll end up subtracting a negative value (and so increase the values instead). Then a[0] will become zero and your program loops.

Initializing `min` with `a[0]` is not enough, you have to look for a valid minimum value. You could, for example, initialize it with a very large value (not a very good solution) or search the array for the first valid min value.

**EDIT:**

I added some prints to your code:

```
...
while (true){
    flag = 0;
    minElem = minElement(a);
    std::cout << "Min: " << minElem << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        a[i] = a[i] - minElem;
    }

    std::cout << "Values:";
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
        std::cout << " " << a[j];
        if (a[j] > 0){
            //cout << " " << a[j];
            flag++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (flag == 0)
        break;

    getchar();
}
...
```

Here's the output:

```
5 4 4 2 2 8
Min: 2
Values: 3 2 2 0 0 6

Min: 2
Values: 1 0 0 -2 -2 4

Min: 1
Values: 0 -1 -1 -3 -3 3

Min: 0
Values: 0 -1 -1 -3 -3 3

(...) Loop forever
```

I hope that helps you understand now what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that I am not even reaching those test cases. This was my input: 
5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 8

Comment: I ran your program and printed the values. I input that too, which is in the link you posted in your question. Edit: Printed ALL the values, not just values higher than 0. Also, try adding `getchar()` at the end of the loop just to see the output of each iteration.

Comment: @randomnessrandomly You are reaching those test cases, I guess you just didn't print the right output for debugging.

Comment: @randomnessrandomly This is the best answer.  If you step through the code, you will see how these numbers are produced, and understand your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

1. `int minElement(int a[]);`  change this to `int minElement(int a[], int size)`

2.

```
int a[6];
for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
    cin >> a[i];
}
```

change this to

```
int arr_size=0;
cout << "Enter the array size ";
cin >> arr_size;

int a[arr_size];
for (int i=0; i<arr_size; i++){
    cin >> a[i];
}
```

3. `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
           a[i] = a[i] - minElem;
       }`
   You are subtracting the min of the array from each element, so at this point there is only one 0 in the array and rest are positive numbers.

   ```
   for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
       if (a[j] > 0){
           cout<<a[j]<<endl;
           flag++;
       }
   ```

So at this point flag has to be some positive number, and in this case 5.

```
   if (flag == 0)
        break;
```

This condition will never hit and hence the infinite loop.

Comment: An array has to be instantiated with a constant value, not a variable. If the length is variable you have to use `new[]`.

Comment: I tried this as well. But was testing with 6 later and just pasted my latest code

Comment: @aslg :  I think it is possible in C++ even with static arrays, but not in C

Comment: If you're referring to the declaration `int minElement(int a[])` this is perfectly legal in both C and C++.  It doesn't allocate an array of ints, but says that the parameter a names a pre-existing array of ints.  It's equivalent to the declaration `int minElement(int *a)`.

Comment: @saulspatz : I did never told it to be illegal, I told to pass size of the array as well for the ease of debugging and making the code flexible by removing the hardcoded loop iterator.

Answer (score 0):

it has nothing to do with the dimension.

What happens is that if a[0] is the smallest value => it will run in an infinte loop. Why because a[0] eventually becomes 0.

Why does a[0]=0 run in an infinte loop?
What value does minElement return when a[0] is 0?
try replace `int min = a[0];` qith `min = (a[0]>0) ? a[0]: 1;`
or adding `minElem= (minElem>0) ? minElem: 1;' after 'minElem = minElement(a);'

**PS:**
Looking at all the answers this seems the simplest minElement that does what you want:

```
int minElement(int a[]){
    int min = a[0];
    int k;
    for (k=1; k < 6; k++){
       if(min==0 && a[k]>0 )
            min=a[k];
       else
        if (a[k] < min and a[k] > 0)
            min = a[k]; 
    }
    return min;
}
```

the min will only be zero at iteration N if a[j]==0 for all j+1

Answer (score 0):

I solve this base on the link you provide. I use vector for me to easy remove those minimum length stick.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main(){
int noOfInput;
int input;
vector<int> myVec;

cin>>noOfInput;
for (int i=0; i<noOfInput; i++){
    cin >> input;
    myVec.push_back(input);
}
sort(myVec.begin(),myVec.end(),greater<int>());
while(myVec.size()>0){
    int minimum = myVec[myVec.size()-1];
    int lengthOfVector = myVec.size();
    cout<<myVec.size()<<" ";
    for(int i = lengthOfVector-1 ; i >=0 ; i--){
        myVec[i]=myVec[i]-minimum;
        if(myVec[i]==0){
            myVec.pop_back();
        }
    }

}


return 0;
}
```