# What does an `auto and T` parameter mean in C++20?

Tags: c++, syntax, c++20, auto

I was shown this code:

```
auto& unmove(auto and T) {
    return T;
}
```

I know `auto` in function parameters is for abbreviated function templates, but then I don't understand what the `and` means. What is this?

Comment: I guess the unexpected part of the duplicate is that the "alternative operator representation" `and` token is interchangeable with `&&` everywhere, even when not used as an operator!  [lex.digraph p2]: "In all respects of the language, each alternative token behaves the same, respectively, as its primary token,
except for its spelling"

Comment: Now, *why* anybody would choose to write the code this way, is another question.  Or why they didn't go the whole way and write `auto bitand unmove(auto and T)`.

Comment: Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71285923) cited nearly the same code.